# Hittest for touches ended in UIWebView

Tags: uiwebview, hittest

I'm using hittest to pick up when a user touches my UIWebview.  I need to know when the user has stopped touching the view, but I don't get any events from hittest.  Is there another function to do this?

```
- (void)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"Event type:%@", event.type);

    if (event.type == UIEventTypeTouches) {
        NSLog(@"Got something");
    }

    // call the super
    [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}
```

Comment: No ideas?  My event type is always "nil" also.

Answer (score 0):

subclass the UIWebView, and implement this method in that class so that you can find touches.
it will execute your if condition.